# (Debian) Unable to connect to X server on Debian and to launch GUI

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, xorg, gui

I bought a new pc without any os and I am trying to boot it under the last Debian version. I am able to boot correctly on my key and to install Debian and the Gnome interface without problems. But then I only have access to the line of command in recovery mode (otherwise it's just a black screen with a waiting cursor but I am not able to write in it).

By looking a bit over the Internet it turns out that the problem might come form Xorg not being able to communicate with the screen. Before going any further I must add that this screen is plugged directly on my graphic card (hdmi/VGA connection) Nvidia Gforce RTX 2060 (is it useful to add that my CPU is an Intel i7-7900KF?).

I first tried to configure Xorg by using `root@username:/# Xorg -configure` in root which results in the creation of xorg.conf.new in the root file. Then doing `cat xorg.conf.new` I obtain :

```
Section "Screen"
      Identifier "Screen0"
      Device "Card0"
      Monitor "Monitor0"
      Subsection "Display"
```

With five different viewports in this display section. The BusID is given a `"PCI:1:0:0"` which I reckon is normal.

However whenever I try to start gnome manually from the line of command with `startx` or `xinit` I obtain the following error:

```
(EE) Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs      for all framebuffers devices
```

followed by a few lines of where to find help and the terrible

```
 xinit:unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
```

I already tried to rm the `.Xauthority`  hidden file as adviced in other forums but it didn't work.

I believe that this problem is coming from the impossibility for my graphic card and my monitor to work together at the moment because of an unspecified property somewhere in the code but I don't know how to solve this. If you have any question about what I have done please just ask, I'll try to answer the best I can, since I am not sure myself.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you might bring.

Vincent